.NET MAUI MSIX icon background and shortcut tile
When i have built the MSIX file from VS2022 and click on it to install the application, in the top right hand corner the icon has a background sitting around my icon.
Also when I create a shortcut on the desktop, it also has a tile background.
For example, in the screenshot below, the green shape represents my icon which has a transparent background, but it is within a blue square.
MSIX Installer
Then for the shortcut, you can see in the screenshot below that it has a blue tile around the icon. (the black colour is just my desktop background)
Desktop Shortcut
I know that this is controlled by the Windows 11 theme, because if I change my theme, the tile colours change.
I need the MSIX installer to just show my icon with no background like many other apps, see the example below:
Advanced installer installer example
Advanced installer shortcut example

Are you using .png or .svg for the icon? I was only able to remove the blue background by using a custom .lnk as a shortcut. Also in your project Platforms/Windows/Package.appx.manifest in Visual Assets, there is Package Logo and various tile settings. You can set the tile background there

Hi @coop,
I'm using a SVG for the app icon.
The shortcut that is on the desktop is already a .lnk file, when you say "custom lnk" is that different to just dragging the app to the desktop from the start menu?
I've attempted to use the built in visual assets generator and set the tile background to "transparent" along with generating all the visual assets, but it doesn't make a difference once the app is packaged and I attempt to install it
